# Non Working Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, database-relations

I got a problem with cake's model architecture.

I got a Users-Model and a Metas-Model. Here are the model codes:

Users:

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {

var $name = 'User';
var $validate = array(
    'username' => array('notempty'),
    'email' => array('email'),
    'password' => array('notempty')
);
    var $displayField = 'username';


var $hasMany = array(
        'Meta' => array(
            'className' => 'Meta',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'        
        )
);

}
?>
```

and the Metas Model:

```
<?php
class Meta extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Meta';

//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed
var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'required' => true
    )
);

}
?>
```

So now the question is why do I not get the Meta data into the User array?
Should I get it in the Auth object?

Or where can I work with the meta data?

Comment: How are you retrieving the array?  If you're talking about the $_SESSION['Auth']['User'] array, note that it's only set on login, and does not include the related models.  If you print_r( $this->User->find(...) ), it should show the attached Meta information.

Comment: yeah with the $this->User->find i get all the meta data

now I want to get the eta data from the current loggedin user :) (in every controller...) what is the best way to do this?

greetz

Answer (score 0):

Your models seem to be fine.The problem must be in your controller file.See [Retrieving data](http://book.cakephp.org/view/73/Retrieving-Your-Data) and [hasMany relation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/82/hasMany) in the cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$currentUserData = $this->User->read(null,$this->Auth->user('id'));
```